# How to get a list of all HTTP PUT "parameters" from the body of the current HTTP request?

Tags: php

I tried with `$_PUT`, but looks like that this variable doesn't exist. There are only `$_GET` and `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` which also just holds `GET`, `POST` and `cookies`.

Comment: Reading the documentation of the tool one uses often helps: http://php.net/manual/de/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: https://lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php Check this out.

Comment: @AlokPatel thanks, i just found the same one a few seconds ago. Before i somehow googled the wrong keywords and i came up empty. This looks really good and simple.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "PUT parameters". The HTTP request that is sent with PUT method contains request body. This body can be read from `php://input` stream.

I found a blog post that describes how the request body can be parsed, if PUT method is used to send POST-like parameters: http://www.chlab.ch/blog/archives/webdevelopment/manually-parse-raw-http-data-php

Comment: The `php://input` got me on the right track. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    echo 'This is a HTTP PUT request.<br />';
    parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $put);
    echo $put['user'] . '<br /><br />';
}
```

Comment: You are treating PUT like POST. If doing that fixes your problem then the correct solution is almost certainly "Use a POST request instead"

Comment: @Quentin I need PUT, PATCH and DELETE for a RESTful API which i'm working on... I can't use only GET and POST.

Comment: There is no requirement that a RESTful API supports every HTTP method. If you are going to treat PUT like POST then there is no reason to support PUT and not just use POST in the first place. If you are going to support PUT then support it properly (i.e. store the *raw* request body so that when the same URL gets a GET request in the future you return that same request body).

Comment: @Quentin i know. But our client wants us to follow this "standard/protocol" (don't know how to call it): https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3 so i have to.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.5 is part of the standard too (but if you are going to support PUT according to the standard, then you have to treat it like PUT and not like POST)

Comment: @Quentin what do you mean by treating it like a PUT and not like POST?

Comment: PUTing something to a URL should simply replace whatever was previously at that URL with what was PUT. It doesn't make much sense to PUT `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data (why would you want a client to make a GET request and receive `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data?). It doesn't make much sense to parse that data on the server (you can just store it as it) although you might want to validate it first. You haven't got any checks to see if you should return a `201` response instead of a `200` response.

Comment: @Quentin right now i'm using PUT to update/replace an entity (user). The client sends the new user data, i then parse it (before this i check if the client is authenticated/has all the necessary privileges), update in the database and return a 200 or 404 HTTP status code. Isn't this how it's supposed to be done? Or is this wrong? It's my first RESTful API. Should i use POST for this instead?